# Can't get thymeleaf parameter in href from model attribute

Tags: html, attributes, thymeleaf, href

I'm new to thymeleaf.
I can't get systemId in th:href ,but I can do it in <p th:text...

What's the problem? Pls, help

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwODH.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ypbl.png)

Comment: just fetch fields of an object, rather than call its methods (e.g <a th:href="@{/releases/${release.releaseId}" >)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace this code
<a th:href="@{|/${systemId}/releases/${release.getReleaseId()}|}"

<a  th:href="@{|/${systemId}/releases/new|}"
the  "| |" is solution of the problem

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html read here 4.8

Comment: Welcome to SO. A brief description of what the "| |" does would be helpful in addition to your link. See "Provide context for links" in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for your links should be:

1: `th:href="@{/{id3}/releases/{id3}(id3=${release.releaseId})}"`

or

1: `th:href="@{/{id3}/releases/{id2}(id3=${release.releaseId}, id2=${release.releaseId})}"`

(if you really want to use 2 different variables for the same value.)

2: `th:href="@{/releases/new/{id}(id=${systemId})}"`